# Replace Scanned Text with OCRed Text in PDF

Tags: pdf, ocr

I have a scanned book as a PDF.

When viewed in Evince, the book appears as it did when scanned, with old fashioned fonts that appear as they were scanned.

However, Evince recognises the letters as characters, and I am able to select, cut, and copy text.

However, the file size is very large and I don't care about the original font type; I would like to replace the original text with the OCRed text so that I can reduce the file size. However, there are images and formatting in the book and I don't want them to be removed.

Is this possible?